# Azure ARM Template failed : could not find 'type'?

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-storage-account

```
{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {
          "storagename": {
            "type": "string",
            "minLength": 4,
            "maxLength": 20
          },

          "location": {
            "type": "string",
            "defaultValue": "[resourceGroup().location]"
          },

          "storagesku": {
             "type": "string",
             "defaultValue": "Standard_LRS"
          },

          "appserviceplanname": {
            "type": "string"
          },

          "appname": {
              "type": "string"
          }
    },
    "functions": [],
    "variables": {
         "uniquestoragename": "[concat(parameters('storagename'),uniqueString(resourceGroup().id))]",
         "uniqueappplanname": "[concat(parameters('appserviceplanname'),uniqueString(resourceGroup().id))]",
         "uniqueappname": "[concat(parameters('appname'),uniqueString(resourceGroup().id))]"
    },
    "resources": [
      {
        "type": "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts",
        "name": "[variables('uniquestoragename')]",
        "apiVersion": "2021-04-01",
        "tags": {
            "displayName": ""
        },
        "location": "[parameters('location')]",
        "kind": "StorageV2",
        "sku": {
            "name": "[parameters('storagesku')]"
        }
      },

      {
        "type": "Microsoft.Web/serverfarms",
        "apiVersion": "2021-02-01",
        "name": "[variables('uniqueappplanname')]",
        "location": "[parameters('location')]",
        "sku": {
          "type": "string",
          "defaultValue": "F1"
        },
        "properties": {
          "reserved": false
        }
      },

      {
        "type": "Microsoft.Web/sites",
        "apiVersion": "2021-02-01",
        "name": "[variables('uniqueappname')]",
        "location": "[parameters('location')]",
        "properties": {
          "httpsOnly": false
          },
        "dependsOn": [
           "[variables('uniqueappplanname')]"
        ]
      }
    ],
    
    "outputs": {}
}
```

After deploying this code in windows power shell I am getting an error message:

New-AzResourceGroupDeployment : 7:34:10 PM - Error: Code=InvalidTemplate; Message=Deployment template parse failed: 'Could not find member 'type' on object of type
'ResourceSku'. Path 'type', line 53, position 19.'.
At line:1 char:1

- New-AzResourceGroupDeployment -Name ramam6466 -ResourceGroupName abhi ...
- ```
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [New-AzResourceGroupDeployment], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Azure.Commands.ResourceManager.Cmdlets.Implementation.NewAzureResourceGroupDeploymentCmdlet
  ```

New-AzResourceGroupDeployment : The deployment validation failed
At line:1 char:1

- New-AzResourceGroupDeployment -Name ramam6466 -ResourceGroupName abhi ...
- ```
    + CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [New-AzResourceGroupDeployment], InvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Azure.Commands.ResourceManager.Cmdlets.Implementation.NewAzureResourceGroupDeploymentCmdlet
  ```

When I deployed only storage account the deployment is succeded. But when I attached the webapp code to deploy webapp with storage the deployments gets failed.

Answer (score 0):

The reason your deployment is failing is because `type` and `defaultValue` are the attributes you specify for template parameters. Also, there are not `type` and `defaultValue` attributes for an App Service Plan resource. Valid attributes are `name` and `tier`.

Please modify your template to use `name` and `tier` attributes in `sku` for your App Service Plan and the deployment should work fine.

Comment: Thanks, Gaurav I was trying to solve the error in the SKU of the resource-storage...as per mentioned error.

Comment: You mentioned that the deployment errors out only when you add web app in the template so I would say that’s where your error is as mentioned in my answer.